# How I can fix black play mode screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, blur, google-cardboard

I am using a blurry material for a cube or plane in Unity3d and when I run the game in play mode it turns black. The cameras are inside the a cube.

I found out that is not the shader's a problem. but google cardboards cameras. Is there any way to fix this problem? when I run it without vr enabled is everything fine.

[image: Screen shot of the black play mode]
[image: Screenshot without play mode that blurry effect is fine]

here is the shader i am using:

```
Shader "Custom/WaterBlur" {
Properties {
_blurSizeXY("BlurSizeXY", Range(0,10)) = 0
}
SubShader {

    Cull off
    // Draw ourselves after all opaque geometry
    Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" }

    // Grab the screen behind the object into _GrabTexture
    GrabPass { }

    // Render the object with the texture generated above
    Pass {


CGPROGRAM
#pragma debug
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag 
#pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _GrabTexture : register(s0);
        float _blurSizeXY;

struct data {

float4 vertex : POSITION;

float3 normal : NORMAL;

};



struct v2f {

  float4 position : POSITION;

  float4 screenPos : TEXCOORD0;

};



v2f vert(data i){

 v2f o;

 o.position = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, i.vertex);

 o.screenPos = o.position;

 return o;

}



half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR

{

float2 screenPos = i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w;
float depth= _blurSizeXY*0.0005;

screenPos.x = (screenPos.x + 1) * 0.5;

screenPos.y = 1-(screenPos.y + 1) * 0.5;

half4 sum = half4(0.0h,0.0h,0.0h,0.0h);   
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-5.0 * depth,  screenPos.y+5.0 * depth)) * 0.025;    
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+5.0 * depth, screenPos.y-5.0 * depth)) * 0.025;

sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-4.0 * depth, screenPos.y+4.0 * depth)) * 0.05;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+4.0 * depth, screenPos.y-4.0 * depth)) * 0.05;


sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-3.0 * depth, screenPos.y+3.0 * depth)) * 0.09;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+3.0 * depth, screenPos.y-3.0 * depth)) * 0.09;

sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-2.0 * depth, screenPos.y+2.0 * depth)) * 0.12;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+2.0 * depth, screenPos.y-2.0 * depth)) * 0.12;

sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-1.0 * depth, screenPos.y+1.0 * depth)) *  0.15;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+1.0 * depth, screenPos.y-1.0 * depth)) *  0.15;



sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-5.0 * depth) * 0.025;    
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-4.0 * depth) * 0.05;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-3.0 * depth) * 0.09;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-2.0 * depth) * 0.12;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-1.0 * depth) * 0.15;    
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos) * 0.16; 
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+5.0 * depth) * 0.15;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+4.0 * depth) * 0.12;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+3.0 * depth) * 0.09;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+2.0 * depth) * 0.05;
sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+1.0 * depth) * 0.025;

return sum/2;

}
ENDCG
    }
 }

Fallback Off
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem is to disable direct render.

This is why google cardboard cameras make the shader look black.